# How to use Sanitizer API in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, sanitization

I need to sanitize an HTML string before sending it to the backend and I'm trying to use the [Sanitizer API mentioned in the Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Sanitizer_API). So I've created the following method in my React project:

```
sanitizeText(unsanitized_string) {
    return new Sanitizer().sanitizeFor(
        "div",
        unsanitized_string,
    ).innerHTML;
}
```

But this is having the following compilation error:

> Line 94:20:  'Sanitizer' is not defined  no-undef

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: just curious, this is experimental and as far as i can see it is not compatible on almost all browsers (web and mobile), see this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Sanitizer/sanitizeFor#browser_compatibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problem

At the time of writing HTML Sanitizer API is still experimental. The error in the question looks like a linting error ([`no-undef`](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-undef)). I assume it's from ESLint. ESLint gets a list of globals from this [package](https://github.com/sindresorhus/globals). Looking in the package's [definition](https://github.com/sindresorhus/globals/blob/main/globals.json) of global variables, the HTML Sanitizer API does not appear. It also doesn't appear to have guidelines for contributing missing types (see [TypeScript's DOM Lib Generator repo](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-DOM-lib-generator#contribution-guidelines) for something similar) so it's not certain how global variables get in or if there's a baseline of support required for an API.

## Solution

### Configuring ESLint

You could make ESLint aware of the global variable. There are several options:

#### Using a configuration comment

At the top of files referencing the global you could add the following:

```
/* global Sanitizer */
```

[Demo](https://eslint.org/play/#eyJ0ZXh0IjoiLyplc2xpbnQgbm8tdW5kZWY6IFwiZXJyb3JcIiovXG4vKiBnbG9iYWwgU2FuaXRpemVyICovXG5cbmZ1bmN0aW9uIHNhbml0aXplVGV4dCh1bnNhbml0aXplZF9zdHJpbmcpIHtcbiAgICByZXR1cm4gbmV3IFNhbml0aXplcigpLnNhbml0aXplRm9yKFxuICAgICAgICBcImRpdlwiLFxuICAgICAgICB1bnNhbml0aXplZF9zdHJpbmcsXG4gICAgKS5pbm5lckhUTUw7XG59XG4iLCJvcHRpb25zIjp7ImVudiI6e30sInJ1bGVzIjp7fSwicGFyc2VyT3B0aW9ucyI6eyJlY21hRmVhdHVyZXMiOnt9LCJlY21hVmVyc2lvbiI6ImxhdGVzdCIsInNvdXJjZVR5cGUiOiJzY3JpcHQifX19)

#### Using a configuration file

In ESLint's configuration file you could add the following:

```
{
  "globals": {
    "Sanitizer": true
  }
}
```

See [documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/language-options#specifying-globals) for more details.

### Contributing to the [globals package](https://github.com/sindresorhus/globals)

You could head to the [globals package](https://github.com/sindresorhus/globals) and open an issue to inquire about adding new globals. The package author may elaborate on contribution guidelines (such as a baseline for support). If they're open to contributions, you could add the definition yourself.

Comment: I don't get this error anymore, even though I have not changed anything. and I don't see it added to the globals json. I will still accept this answer as it clears the reason behind the error and it's very informative. I am also dropping the usage of Sanitizer for now because of the lack of support. Thank you so much for the help, Wing!